# SQL: get current online player count using login/logout timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` table that comprises uid, login/logout status flat, timestamp, for example:

```
uid    flag    time
123    login   10:00:00
123    logout  10:10:00
321    login   10:08:00
321    logout  10:18:00
```

Now I want to display online player count for every minute between 10:08 to 10:09. What is expected:

```
Minute    current_player_cnt 
10:07         1
10:08         2
10:09         2
```

I can export data as csv file and do this using python, but I want directly do this using sql and cannot find a function that could help.

You do not need to give the entire sql sentence, just give a function name will be fine. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: @D-Shih Hi, my mysql version is `5.7.23`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to join using a calendar table, e.g.

```
SELECT
    t1.Minute,
    COUNT(t2.uid) AS current_player_cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT '10:07:00' AS Minute UNION ALL
    SELECT '10:08:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '10:09:00'
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT uid, MIN(time) AS login_time, MAX(time) AS logout_time
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY uid
) t2
    ON t1.Minute BETWEEN t2.login_time AND t2.logout_time OR
       (t1.Minute >= t2.login_time AND t2.login_time = t2.logout_time)
GROUP BY
    t1.Minute;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: What if someone didn't log out yet? :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works, but if I want to show online player count for every minute between `10:08` to `20:09`, this would not be practical. Is there a function that can return every minute?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Appreciate your feedback as always, I think I patched that edge case.

Comment: @user2894829 If you don't already have all those points of time in a table, then you will probably need to generate them somehow.  Google around for generating a calendar table in MySQL.  Explaining how to do that here is out of scope for your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see. Thanks for your detailed reply.